# Internal involute spline 1.375 - 21T

Tags: mechanical

could anybody help me by providing an internal involute spline data sheet similar to the attached picture for an 1-3/8" splined shaft with 21 teeth, 16DP and 30 degree pressure angle.
Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Machinery's Handbook for a flat root side fit spline. There are a few other different styles, this is what I use. This is a class 5 tolerance (typical industry level) per ANSI B92.1-1970

[image: 21T16P30A]

Comment: would you be willing to also provide the external spline information of an 1.375-21T spline. That would speed things up at my end.

Comment: @Jakob Arent - he’s provided you with the source, so you can research for yourself! This is the first result on google for “Machinery's Handbook PDF” http://library.uc.edu.kh/userfiles/pdf/19.Machinery's%20handbook.pdf

Comment: Ok, thanks. And yes you are right with a bit of research and calculation i could have found out the most of them. But i am still struggling with the max. actual space width and min actual width and cant find out what is the right way. Even after researching on some websites there seams to be no clear answer. Could somebody explain how it works?

Comment: Drawing data - external spline    
Flat root side fit    
Number of teeth 21  ea 
Diametral pitch 16 32 pitch/stub 
Pressure angle 30  deg 
Base diameter 1.1367  in REF
Pitch diameter 1.3125  in REF
Major diameter 1.375  in 
Form diameter 1.246  in 
Minor diameter 1.228  in MIN
    
Pin diameter 0.1200  in 
Min over 2 pins 1.4929  in 
Max over 2 pins 1.4947  in 
    
Max actual tooth thickness 0.0967  in 
Min actual tooth thickness 0.0955  in

Comment: Sorry that spreadsheet didn't paste well into text, but the data is there. Basically the max actual space and min actual width are offset from the perfect theoretical dimensions allowing for variation in the tooth form and variations in your manufacturing process. It ensures your spline teeth will actually mesh by adding some extra clearance, typically a few thousandths (0.001").